# Please help with mathematical induction to prove that $f(x) = (n+xn) \bmod {2n-1} =x$ if $x$ is odd, $x\geq1$?

Tags: number-theory

My method is like this :

for $x = 1$, $f(1) = 2n \mod (2n-1) =1$, true

If $x$ is odd then $x$ can be written as $2j-1$, $j\geq1$,

It is assumed that it is true for $x = 2k-1$, $f(2k-1) = n+(2k-1)n  \mod (2n-1) =2nk \mod (2n-1)=k$

It will be shown for $x = 2(k+1)-1$ is true

$f(2(k+1)-1)=n+(2(k+1)-1)n) \mod (2n-1) = n + 2kn + n \mod (2n-1) = 2n(k+1) \mod (2n-1) = k+1$

I am stuck till this step.
Help please

Comment: Please consider using "\bmod" instead of just writing "mod".

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is wrong.  It should be $f(x)\equiv(n+xn)\equiv\frac{x+1}{2}\bmod (2n-1)$ for all odd $x\ge1$.

Base case: $f(1)\equiv2n\equiv1\bmod (2n-1)$

Induction hypothesis: $f(2k-1)\equiv(n+(2k-1)n)\equiv\frac{(2k-1)+1}{2}\equiv k\bmod (2n-1)$

Inductive step: $f(2(k+1)-1)\equiv f(2k+1)\equiv(n+(2k+1)n)\equiv\frac{(2k+1)+1}{2}\equiv k+1\bmod (2n-1)$

Hence we're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway, but is it mathematically wrong if I write for example in your answer $f(1) = 2n = 1 \bmod (2n-1)$ becoming $f(1) = 2n \bmod (2n-1) = 1$ ?

Comment: @wawarji I hope I understand you correctly.  I see you using $=$ instead of $\equiv$ above for $\bmod(2n-1)$, so to be lazy and to save time, I typed $=$ instead of $\equiv$.  I'll change them back to clarify things

Comment: so there is no problem if I write $f(1) = 2n \bmod (2n-1) = 1$. Thanks

Comment: @wawarji I see.  I'll be more careful about that.  In fact, using $\equiv$ and putting $\bmod$ at the right is more convenient.